# File reader not reading correct values

Tags: java, file-io

I'm pretty new to Java, and I've written two small functions to read and write data to a file. The data being written is the x and y coordinates of a character on the map in a game. The data written to the file seems to be all right:

```
234
-123
```

I write the data with the following code:

```
public void save(int x, int y)
{
    try
    {
        FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("skygrim.txt");  //Create save-file
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);    //New writer, connected to save-file
        out.write(x + "\n" +y);        //Write position to file 
        out.close();                   //Close file
    }catch (Exception e){System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());}
}
```

When I later want to read the data, to be able to "load" a saved game, I get the following values from the file:

```
50
51
```

I use the following code to read from the file:

```
public int[] read(String file)
{
    int[] coordinates = new int[2];
    try
    {
        FileReader fstream = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(fstream);
        coordinates[0] = in.read();
        coordinates[1] = in.read();
        in.close();
    }catch(Exception e){System.out.println("Error" + e.getMessage());}
    System.out.println("x: " + coordinates[0]);
    System.out.println("y: " + coordinates[1]);
    return coordinates;
}
```

Why does the program read the file so terribly wrong, and what can I do about it?

Comment: Always close streams and readers in a finally block. Or use the Java 7 try-with-resources. The Java API is very well documented. Reading the javadoc would have told you why your code doesn't work. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read%28%29

Answer (score 9, accepted):

your read method is reading the first two characters of the file: '2' and '3'. You probably want to use BufferedReader.readLine()

Also see Integer.parseInt(String)

Comment: Thanks for this comment! After a bit of time staring at a similar problem, this was exactly my mistake! :facepalm:

Answer (score 2):

`BufferedReader.read()` reads a single character, not an `int`. A possibility would be to use `java.util.Scanner` and its method `nextInt()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 coordinates[0] = in.read();
 coordinates[1] = in.read();
```

Only read one byte with each call. In this case you are getting '2' and '3' (50 and 51 are their ascii code). And hence the wrong value.

Comment: It doesn't read one byte. It reads one character. But the diagnostic is the right one.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `readLine()` method of your `BufferedReader` object to avoid reading a single character as `read()` method does.

```
coordinate[0] = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
coordinate[1] = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
```